# PHP: Tell if a file exists?

Tags: php, php4

I need to be able to tell if an image exists in a directory or not. Given the file name and the directory, how can I tell if it exists?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh come on now - PHP has some very fine manuals!

Comment: And Google'll find them. http://www.google.com/search?q=php+file+exists

Comment: @Paul good point..I should have used Google first... By the way SO must get indexed fast because this page is already in the top results when I searched it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
file_exists($filename);
```

http://www.php.net/file_exists

Comment: It's important to note that `file_exists` will return true for a directory as well as a file; if you also want to make sure that it's really a file, you want `is_file` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
$dir = '/var/img/'; $name = 'img.jpg';

echo is_file($dir.$name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool file_exists(string $filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know more than file_exists() you should look at the stat function... It can tell you if a file exists and if so how big it is, and what type of file it is (and about a dozen other things)...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
?>
```

Source: http://in.php.net/file_exists

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about image... possibly you try to find a way to put some "no-picture" image instead of nonexistent?

If yes - look at something like [this](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/emitimage.html). Else read the manual as people said before...